# `ArrayList of HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap` to get item by index

Tags: java, collections

My need to store a a huge amount of data in the key-value form.
Also, I have two requirements

1. query data via the index, like from an array.
2. hence the order in the data structure must be preserved.

For Requirement 2 - I can use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

For Requirement 1 - I have two options :

- 1.1 | To implement **an ArrayList Of HashMap**. [`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`]
- 1.2  | To implement a **LinkedHashMap** and query the items by index using something like

  - -> `new ArrayList(hashMapObject.entrySet()).get(0);`

The Question is which is better among `1.1` or `1.2` ?

By better, I mean - **efficient in terms of memory and space.**

Let's assume the volume of data is in the order of 50 to 100 key-value pairs with average sized Strings - say every key is 10-30 characters and value is 30-50 characters.

Comment: Why don't you just measure? Measuring is knowing.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a Hashmap? Couldn't you just use an arraylist of String pairs?

Comment: HashMap are unordered collections and thus the index has no meaning.  If you need an index, you are using the wrong collection.

Comment: @BalusC i might end up doing that, if someone hasn't already experimented with this.

Comment: @resueman What is an ArrayList of String pairs?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa I just mean an ArrayList storing some object containing 2 strings; either a custom defined object, or something like java.util.Map.Entry

Comment: Do you need to be able to query by key as well? If so, which should be faster - query by key, or by index?

Comment: How many distinct keys are you planning to store? I understand that each group would have about 100 of different keys, but if you analyze all the groups and take the union of all keys, how many keys are you going to get?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Every key is going to be unique. But what did you have in mind?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa If most KVPs had mostly identical sets of keys (say, you've got max 120 unique keys, with KVP groups taking a subset of 50..100 of the 120 keys), then you could store a "schema" that maps a key to an integer index, and then store arrays of 120 objects, some of them being null.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa Is all keys being unique a definite requirement that is not going to change? This could be exploited quite nicely if it is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : yes, they are always going to be unique. How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with experimentating it myself. Turns out the method of creating an **ArrayList of HashMaps** is about **40 times faster with 1000 elements.**

```
public class HashMapVsArrayOfHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMaps=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for( int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            final int finalI=i;
        listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("asdfasdfasdfasdfadsf"+finalI,"asdfsdafasdfsadfasdf"+finalI);}});
        }
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            map.put("asdfasdfasdfasdfadsf"+i,"asdfsdafasdfsadfasdf"+i);     
        int position=700;
        testArrayList("Method1:ArrayListOfHashMaps",position,listOfMaps);
        testHashMap("Method2:LinkedHashMap",position,map);
    }

    private static void testArrayList(String string, int position,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMaps) {
        long start, end;
        start=System.nanoTime();
        listOfMaps.get(position).get("asdfasdfasdfasdfadsf"+position);
        end=System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(string+"|Difference = "+(end-start));        
    }
    private static void testHashMap(String string, int position,
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
        long start, end;
        start=System.nanoTime();

        String s= new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet()).get(position);

        end=System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(string+"|Difference = "+(end-start));        
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**When you increase the size to 30,000 elements - the difference is HUGE.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using SortedMap.

For example:

```
SortedMap<Key, Value> map = new TreeMap<Key, Value>();
```

This way you get the fast lookup time (via key), but they also remain ordered.

You can then iterate over the data like so:

```
for(Key k : map.keySet()) { 
    process(map.get(k)); 
}
```

I used them recently to analyze 10s millions tweets where the key was a date, and the value was a counter. I wanted to maintain the ordering of the dates.

**update** If you can get by with just itereating over the data, then my method will suffice. Perhaps you could supply a small example? If it's absolutely required that you can reference the data by index as well, it seems like you would just want to maintain two datastructures like @Jim mentioned. I'ved had to do that before.

Comment: "If you can get by with just itereating over the data, then my method will suffice" - how will it be different in any other case?

Comment: Because if you have to directly index the data structure, data[index], it usually means you need random access the data. i.e. read index 14, then 10, then 1, then 13. However many times people really just need to loop over the data, in which case you can just do something like `for(Key k : map.keySet()) { process(map.get(k)); }`, which is very fast, and removes the usually unecessary need to directly index the data, while at the same time preserving your key order because we are using a `SortedMap`

Answer (score 3):

Remember that collections do not contain the objects, only *references* to objects.

Use *two* collections:

1. An `ArrayList` to store the references for access by index
2. A `HashMap` to store the references for access by key

For example:

```
List<MyValue> list = new ArrayList<MyValue>(100000);
Map<MyKey,MyValue> map = new HashMap<MyKey,MyValue>(100000);

while(moreItems) {
    // read input
    MyKey key = ...
    MyValue value = ...
    list.add(value);
    map.put(key,value);
}

// lookup by index
MyValue v1 = list.get(11241);
// lookup by key
MyValue v2 = map.get(someKey);
```

If you need to cross-reference (i.e. given a value object, find its index or its key) you have some options:

1. Save the index and key in the the value object itself
2. Wrap the value in a "handle" that contains the key and index.

For example

```
class Wrapper {
    MyKey   key;
    MyValue value;
    int     index;
    // constructor, getters and setters
}

int index=0;
while(moreItems) {
    // read input
    MyKey key = ...
    MyValue value = ...
    Wrapper w = new Wrapper(key,value,index++);
    list.add(w);
    map.put(key,w);
}
...
Wrapper w = list.get(23410);
MyKey k = w.getKey();
MyValue v = w.getValue();
int i = w.getIndex();
...
```

Comment: do you mean `for(i=100000;i>0;i++) arrayList.add("abc")` is same as `for(i=100000;i>0;i++) arrayList.add("abc")` in terms of memory usage?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa actually your loops should be `for(i=100000;i>0;i--)`. And both of your loops are the exact same. However, if what you meant to ask about a list containing 5 "abc"s compared to a list containing 10000 "abc"s then the answer is still no, because there is memory overhead in using the ArrayList collection, At a bare minimum you would have to store many references. However, the Strings "abc" are immutable and have the same hashcodes. Java will check internally to see if the String has been created before, if it has it will return a reference rather than create a new String object.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa Here is an interesting post about how the JVM handles String objects in memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076099/avoid-duplicate-strings-in-java

Comment: @KennyCason im sorry, i meant "`for(i=100000;i>0;i--)` & `for(i=2;i>0;i--)`"

And i know about the immutable property of the String.. i meant to ask if the same object, if added multiple times in a Collection, would take the memory equivalent to being added a single time?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa I answered that starting from "At a bare minimum..." also the link i posted elaborates on how the JVM handles that as well.

Comment: @KennyCason Reading it after an year. Makes more sense now (now that i understand java a bit better). All your comments seem very correct.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the LinkedHashMap is the best solution, but to get the item, you can use

```
hashMapObject.values().toArray()[index]
```

However, the toArray method will be slow for large amounts of data. But that is something you'll have to test.

If speed is really an issue, you can maintain a HashMap **and** an ArrayList.

Comment: you mean why the toArray method will be slow? Because it will iterate through all objects in the HashMap. See AbstractCollection#toArray