# HashMaps in Java - Indexed or not

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set

The question:
Is the HashMap(Map) we use in java indexed or not ? And if it is indexed, could you please explain it briefly ?

Comment: (Welcome to (posting on) SO!) What does `indexed` mean here, and where does that definition come from? Is it *implements [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html)*? If this is an assignment: what have you been shown to determine whether an interface/class is `indexed`, and how does that apply to `HashMap(Map)`?

Comment: We actually don't even know what you mean by "indexed". That word has too many meanings to be unambiguous when used by someone starting out in software development.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap, which orders elements by insertion. Reference: [Java - get index of key in HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686092/java-get-index-of-key-in-hashmap)

Answer (score 1):

HashMaps contain key&value pairs. Every key may only exist once.

You cannot get values using an index, but need to use the method

```
 HashMap.get()
```

A decent tutorial can be found here: 
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/

Answer (score 1):

[HashMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) are an implementation of a Hash Table. The hashCode() function, that all Classes inherit from the Object class, is used to, ideally, produce a unique integer. The hashCode integer is used to map an object value to a location where, assuming low collisions, search time is O(1). If the hashCode() function is poor and produces the same value for many keys within the HashMap, search time may degrade (The HashMap will rehash itself once the number of entries in the Map exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity).

In a sense, HashMaps are indexed and that is what enables their good performance. However, they are not indexed in the manner you could obtain an item from index and the HashMap class will not ensure that order is retained; you will need to use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).